# Let n and k be integers such that $n > k ≥ 0$. Show that ${n\choose k }$+ ${n\choose k + 1 }$ = ${n + 1\choose k + 1 }$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to prove it using algebra and it didn't get very far. Here is how far I got.

Now I know  ${n\choose k } = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

So the entire expression would be

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} + \frac{n!}{(k + 1)!(n-k-1)!} = \frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}$$

I first start multiplying ${\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}}$ by $(k + 1)!$ and get:
$$\frac{n!(k+1)}{(k+1)!(n-k)!} + \frac{n!}{(k + 1)!(n-k-1)!} = \frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}$$

I see that I'm missing a negative $-1$ in my right hand side and left hand side and stuck wondering how to properly manipulate the equation.

Comment: Multiply top and bottom of the first by $k+1$, and top and bottom of the second by $n-k$.  Now the two expressions have the same denominator. $(k+1)!(n-k)!$. Add the numerators. We get $n!(k+1)+n!(n-k)=n!(n+1)=(n+1)!$. (This has been done often on MSE.)

Comment: Hint $(n-k-1)!=(n-k)!/(n-k)$

Answer (score 5):

Well you can start by the following:  $$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}+\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}=\frac{n!\times (k+1)}{k!\times (k+1)(n-k)!}+\frac{n!\times (n-k)}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!\times (n-k)}$$
$$=\frac{n!\times (k+1)}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}+\frac{n!\times (n-k)}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}$$
$$=\frac{n!(k+1+n-k)}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}=\frac{n!(n+1)}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}.$$
So you get  $$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}+\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}.$$